# jQuery Validate ABA Routing number not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So Im  trying to validate An ABA routing number and have partial success. The bulk of the code seems to work but for some reason its just focusing on the first three digits instead of looking at all 9.

this is begining to annoy me and im sure its something silly I'm just overlooking.

Here is the reference to the original code: [brainjar](http://www.brainjar.com/js/validation/)

Here is my JS fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93jt15qm)

and bellow is my code:

```js
function ABA(t) {
 // Run through each digit and calculate the total.
var n = 0,
 $this = $(t),
 tval = $this.val();
  for (i = 0; i < $this.length; i += 3) {
    n += parseInt(tval.charAt(i),     10) * 3
      +  parseInt(tval.charAt(i + 1), 10) * 7
      +  parseInt(tval.charAt(i + 2), 10);
  }

  // If the resulting sum is an even multiple of ten (but not zero),
  // the aba routing number is good.
if($this.val().length == 9){
  if (n != 0 && n % 10 == 0){
   setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('invalid');
    $this.addClass('valid');
    }, 500);
  }else{
   setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('valid');
    $this.addClass('invalid');
   }, 500);}
    

} else {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('valid');
    $this.addClass('invalid');
   }, 500);}

}

$('#abaR').on('input', function() {
ABA(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="abaR" maxlength="9" id="abaR">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

`for (i = 0; i < tval.length; i += 3) {`

`$this` is a jQuery object, not the string; it's `length` will always be 1, which is why it appeared to only inspect the first three digits.  It seems to work with my own bank's routing number.